# “git: command not found” when running “pm2 deploy production setup”

Tags: linux, git, azure, ssh, pm2

I'm hosting a Ghost blog on a Linux Azure VM, but I'm having trouble setting up PM2 deploy.

The issue I'm getting in Git Bash in local Windows:

[image: git: command not found]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git is missing on remote server!